# Gateaux Diff and Frechet diff

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

yesterday I took a test and I can't answer this question.
“Let $E,F$ be two normative spaces and f be a function on E to F with Gateaux differential and all limits
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$
It exists uniformly for all $v \in S_E(0,1)$ then f is Frechet diff. “

My teacher told me that if you understand compactness in $S_E(0,1)$ you can solve that, but I don't know what it means. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think compactness is needed here. In fact, the result should hold for arbitrary normed spaces (whether they have finite or infinite dimension). The uniform assumption means that there is a bounded linear map $A_x$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$\sup_{v\in S(0;1)}\Big|\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}-A_xv\Big|_F<\varepsilon$$
whenever $0<|t|<\delta$.

Define $r(x;h)=f(x+h)-f(x)+A_xh$. Let $v_h=\frac{1}{|h|_E}h$. Then, if $|h|_E<\delta$ we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{|r(x;h)|_F}{|h|_E}&=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-A_xh|_F}{|h|_E}\\
&=\Big|\frac{f(x+|h|v_h)-f(x)}{|h|_E}-A_xv_h\Big|_F<\varepsilon
\end{align}
This means that $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable at $x$ and that $f'(x)=A_x$.